# SQLAlchemy: Updates on persistent object are auto flushed when autoflush=False

Tags: sqlalchemy

When applying updates to a persistent object, it seems that each update is automatically pushed to the transaction buffer even when the `autoflush` property is set as false.

Consider the following example. There are two entities - *Employee* and *Department*, and they have a many-to-many relationship between them.
The ORM definition is as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry, relationship

mapper_registry = registry()

mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
   models.Employee,
   employee_table,
   properties={
       "employee_id": employee_table.c.EmployeeId,
       "first_name": employee_table.c.FirstName,
       "last_name": employee_table.c.LastName,
       "departments": relationship(
           models.Department, secondary=joinEmployeeDepartment
       ),
   },
)
```

The initial database state looks like this:

Employee:

| EmployeeId | FirstName | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe |

Department:

| DepartmentId | DepartmentName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sales |

joinEmployeeDepartment:

| RelationshipId | EmployeeId | DepartmentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

Then the following code is executed:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session, sessionmaker

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False)

session = Session()
session.begin()
try:
   employee: Employee = session.query(Employee).where(Employee.first_name == 'John').one_or_none()
   employee.departments = [Department(department_name='support')]  # 1
   employee.departments = [Department(department_name='IT')]       # 2
   session.commit()
finally:
   session.close()
```

Since `autoflush` is turned off, I would expect that when the persistent employee object is updated in-memory in #1, the changes would not be flushed to transaction buffer. Since #2 overwrites the changes made in #1, only the latter would be flushed and committed when `session.commit()` is called. However, I observed that is not the case. The change in #1 is also added to the transaction buffer. The resulting DB state is as follows:

Department:

| DepartmentId | DepartmentName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sales |
| 2 | support |
| 3 | IT |

joinEmployeeDepartment:

| RelationshipId | EmployeeId | DepartmentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |

My question is that is the `autoflush` setting ignored when updates are made to a persistent object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that as each new `Department` instance is created, it's added to `session.new` and enters the *pending* [state](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_state_management.html#quickie-intro-to-object-states).  A pending object

> [isn't] actually flushed to the database yet, but it will be when the next flush occurs.

So when the session is flushed commit, it finds two pending `Department` instances and sends them to the database.

The "delete" of the first `Department` instance is not tracked in `session.deleted` because that instance is not in a persistent state.  Thus at flush time no `DELETE` is sent for that instance.  However SQLAlchemy's attribute tracking tracks it as having been deleted from the relationship, so SQLAlchemy fixes the many-to-many mappings to reflect the final desired state.

We can see this by printing `session.new` and the relationship's history, and enabling logging on the engine:

```py
with Session() as s:
    employee: Employee = s.query(Employee).where(Employee.first_name == 'John').one_or_none()
    hist = sa.inspect(employee).attrs.departments.history
    employee.departments = [Department(department_name='support')]
    print(s.new)
    print(sa.inspect(employee).attrs.departments.history)
    employee.departments = [Department(department_name='IT')]
    print(s.new)
    print(sa.inspect(employee).attrs.departments.history)
    s.commit()
```

Output:

```
2021-12-08 11:42:40,134 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-12-08 11:42:40,139 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT employees.id AS employees_id, employees.first_name AS employees_first_name, employees.last_name AS employees_last_name 
FROM employees 
WHERE employees.first_name = ?
2021-12-08 11:42:40,139 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00028s] ('John',)
2021-12-08 11:42:40,143 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT departments.id AS departments_id, departments.department_name AS departments_department_name 
FROM departments, association 
WHERE ? = association.employee_id AND departments.id = association.department_id
2021-12-08 11:42:40,143 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00024s] (1,)
IdentitySet([<__main__.Department object at 0x7fdbf4998eb0>])
History(added=[<__main__.Department object at 0x7fdbf4998eb0>], unchanged=[], deleted=[<__main__.Department object at 0x7fdbf4882860>])
IdentitySet([<__main__.Department object at 0x7fdbf4998eb0>, <__main__.Department object at 0x7fdbf4881420>])
History(added=[<__main__.Department object at 0x7fdbf4881420>], unchanged=[], deleted=[<__main__.Department object at 0x7fdbf4882860>])
2021-12-08 11:42:40,145 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO departments (department_name) VALUES (?)
2021-12-08 11:42:40,145 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.01444s ago] ('support',)
2021-12-08 11:42:40,145 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO departments (department_name) VALUES (?)
2021-12-08 11:42:40,145 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.01477s ago] ('IT',)
2021-12-08 11:42:40,147 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine DELETE FROM association WHERE association.employee_id = ? AND association.department_id = ?
2021-12-08 11:42:40,147 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00023s] (1, 1)
2021-12-08 11:42:40,148 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO association (employee_id, department_id) VALUES (?, ?)
2021-12-08 11:42:40,148 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.01509s ago] (1, 3)
2021-12-08 11:42:40,148 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

To prevent the insertion of the first `Department` it must be removed from `session.new` by [expunging](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.expunge) it from the session:

```py
    employee.departments = [Department(department_name='support')]
    s.expunge(employee.departments[0])
    employee.departments = [Department(department_name='IT')]
```

See the docs for sessions and [object states](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_events.html#object-lifecycle-events) for more detail.